# How to read data faster in Qt?

Tags: c#, qt

Does Qt read database slower than C#? I think I am missing something! To compare reading speed I have written folllowing in Qt

```
QElapsedTimer t;
t.start();
int count = 0;
QString cs = "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=EMON;Database=FAODB;User=Test;Password=Test";
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC",cs);
db.setDatabaseName(cs);
db.open();
QSqlQuery query(db);
query.setForwardOnly(true);
query.exec("SELECT * FROM FAOCropsLivestock");
while(query.next()){
    if(query.value("Country").toString() == "\"Bangladesh\"")
        count++;
}
db.close();
qDebug()<< QString::number(count) + " elapsed ms " + QString::number(t.elapsed());
```

and in C#

```
Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
s.Start();
int count = 0;
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;
string query = "SELECT * FROM FAOCropsLivestock";
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs)){
      using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con)){
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rd.Read()){
                  if(rd["Country"].ToString() == "\"Bangladesh\"")
                        count++;                       
            }
      }
}
s.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(count + " elapsed ms " + s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Both C# and Qt are for `x86` and on Release mode.

In Qt's case the result was `"63653 elapsed ms 68213"`
and in C# `"63653 elapsed ms 14210"`

---

For Qt version I have replaced

```
QString cs = "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=EMON;Database=FAODB;User=Test;Password=Test";
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC",cs);
db.setDatabaseName(cs);
```

by

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC" /*QODBC3*/);
db.setDatabaseName("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"\
                   "Server=EMON;Database=FAODB;Uid=Test;Pwd=Test;");
```

Results were in between 58s - 71s.

Comment: I would time more things first to narrow it down. Maybe the qt `Open` call takes 54 seconds for some reason.. Try timing just the `while` loops separately to verify that executing the query itself is what's taking up most of the 68 seconds.

Comment: @Quantic in that case Qt's best was `54s` and C# `13s`

Comment: Did you run both in release mode?

Comment: As mentioned, Yes @ThomasAyoub

Answer (score 0):

For your C# version, you don't show your connection string. Are you using the same drivers for both? I'm not an expert on this, but my colleague who is says that the "SQL Server" driver is very, very old and slow. You probably want to try "SQL Native Client" or something along those lines. Either way, be sure that the test is using the same SQL driver.

Comment: It is same as writing `string cs = "Server=EMON;Database=FAODB;user=Test;password=Test";`. I am not sure which driver is being used by C#. I just have to add `using System.Data.SqlClient;` to access MS SQL Server.

Comment: I'm not sure which driver .NET uses with System.Data.SqlClient, but I suspect that's the difference. Try updating your C++ code with a current driver and retesting.

Comment: I've tried with `QODBC3` and `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` but it did not change the result. I have added the code in my post @goug

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?