# How to use ADODB.Connection in Qt and query database?

Tags: sql-server, qt

As shown [in my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192841/how-to-read-data-faster-in-qt) QODBC/QODBC3 is not that good to work with databases. I have found a year old suggestion [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/61946/connect-to-sql-server/2) to use ADODB for SQL Server. Can anyone give an example showing or suggest a link explaining How to connect, query and get result using ADODB.Connection in Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `QAxObject`.

First you should take a look at:

- `QAxObject` documentation: [doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxobject.html](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxobject.html)
- Active X data object documentation: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676795(v=vs.85).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676795(v=vs.85).aspx)

Here is a sample code to get you started:

```
// Create connection
QAxObject *connection = new QAxObject("ADODB.Connection");
connection->dynamicCall("Open(\"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Inaz;Data Source=SERVER02\")");

// Execute query and get recordset
QAxObject *recordSet = connection->querySubObject("Execute(\"select column01 from table01\")");
// Get fields
// or check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681510(v=vs.85).aspx to see what you can do with and how to use a recordset
QAxObject *fields = recordSet->querySubObject("Fields");
```

Note: You will need to call `CoInitialize` to use ADODB. However QGuiApplication and QApplication call it internally so you might not always need to make the call yourself.

Comment: I get 1) `error: conversion from 'QAxObject*' to non-scalar type 'QAxObject' requested QAxObject connection = new QAxObject("ADODB.Connection");`  2) `error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'QAxObject' connection->dynamicCall("Open(\"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Data Source=EMON\")");` in main.cpp of QtQuick Applcation.

Comment: I messes the pointer semantic in the code sample. I've submitted a fix. Anyway the code sample is only here to get you started with the philosophy of QAxObject. You should check examples provided in Qt documentation.